# How decode unicode string in tasypie result

Tags: json, django, unicode, utf-8, tastypie

I have some REST application based on django and django-tastypie

```
class CompanyResource(BaseResource):

    class Meta:

        queryset =      Company.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'company/company'
        allowed_mathods=('get', 'path')
        filtering = {
            'id':       ALL,
            'category': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'name':     ('exact', 'icontains'),
            'synonyms': ('icontains', ),
        }
```

It work fine. Response looks like this:

```
{
    "meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 2}, 
    "objects": [{"_active": true, "name": "Рога и копыта"}]
}
```

But when I try to customize result:

```
def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
    resp = super(CompanyResource, self).get_list(request, **kwargs)

    data = json.loads(resp.content)

    if request.GET.get('query', False) :

        query = request.GET.get('query')
        reg_query = re.escape(query)

        for i, object in enumerate(data['objects']):

            # some logic here
            data['objects'][i]['blah-bla-blah'] = query.split()

    data = json.dumps(data, encoding='utf-8',)

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json', status=200)
```

I see unicode escaped strings in response

```
{
    "meta": ..., 
    "objects": [{"_active": true, "name": "\u0420\u043e\u0433\u0430 \u0438 \u043a\u043e\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430", "blah-bla-blah": "blah-blah-blah_data"}]
}
```

How return data with UTF strings?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate, similar question with good answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280513/tastypie-json-header-to-use-utf-8