# Django-tastypie: utf8 is incorrect

Tags: python, django, unicode, utf-8, tastypie

```
class ActionResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = ActionInfo.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'action'

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['name'] = bundle.obj.name
        bundle.data['expect_time'] = bundle.obj.expect_time
        bundle.data['type'] = bundle.obj.type
        bundle.data['price'] = bundle.obj.price
        bundle.data['additional'] = bundle.obj.additional
        return bundle
```

This code from resource.py. Charfields that have russian letters print incorrect, for example: name: "РЎРѕР»СЏРЅРєР°". I've added at the top of the resource.py:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

and return string from django models:

```
class ActionName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ActionInfo(models.Model):
    name        = models.ForeignKey(ActionName,     related_name="title",    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    expect_time = models.ForeignKey(ActionDuration, related_name="duration",on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    type        = models.ForeignKey(ActionType,     related_name="type",    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    available   = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=True)
    price       = models.ForeignKey(ActionPrice,    related_name="price",   on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
---------------------------------------------
```

returned json:

```
{
additional: " 280 Рі ",
available: true,
comments: null,
discription: "",
expect_time: null,
id: 120,
name: "РЎРѕР»СЏРЅРєР°",
photo: "/images/83913-220-184-solyanka_2.jpg",
rate: null,
resource_uri: "/api/v1/action/120/",
type: "РџРµСЂРІС‹Рµ Р±Р»СЋРґР°",
}
```

Who knows how to fix it?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280513/tastypie-json-header-to-use-utf-8
Here is answer on my question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `__str__()` use `__unicode__()`. And use [smart_text](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.smart_text):

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text

class ActionName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300) 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_text(self.name)
```

BTW: Instead of `dehydrate()` use fields:

```
from tastypie import fields

class ActionResource(ModelResource):
    name = fields.CharField('name__name', null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = ActionInfo.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'action'
```

BTW2:

```
>>> print u'РЎРѕР»СЏРЅРєР°'.encode('windows-1251')
Солянка
>>> print u'РЎРѕР»СЏРЅРєР°'.encode('windows-1251').decode('utf8')
Солянка
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help

Comment: yes, only tastypie print text incorect, in other apps text is good

Comment: Instead of `bundle.obj.name` try `unicode(bundle.obj.name)`

Comment: Same, nothing change. Encode and decode nothing change too.

Comment: bundle.data['name'] = unicode(bundle.obj.name.name).encode("windows-1251").decode('utf8')
Gives error:
"'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte",

Comment: `bundle.obj.name.name.decode("windows-1251").encode(‌​'utf8')`

Comment: name: "Р РЋР С•Р В»РЎРЏР Р…Р С”Р В°",

Comment: Are You sure this is a proper string?

Comment: bundle.data['name'] = bundle.obj.name.name.decode('windows-1251').encode('utf8')

return for me it. This string was changed, but not in the right way. Is there some function to print text in dehydrate method or maybe more informative traceback? Because i can't properly debug my code or even check variables. DB postgresql: encoding: utf8, django 1.9, python 2.7

Comment: get row with this string in other app and try to print it.

Comment: obj = ActionInfo.objects.get(pk = 120)
    print obj.name

Looks good in console

Comment: "This string was changed, but not in the right way" - it's probably saved in UTF8. Save it in Windows-1251, like others. Or save others strings in UTF8.

Comment: All data i get via BeautifulSoup and before saving to db i use this:
text.encode('utf-8'). Or i must save it with decode("windows-1251") too?

Comment: Based on previous experiences, yes.

Comment: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 14: character maps to <undefined>

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: � ���������

 variable 'text': 
u'\u0421\u0430\u043b\u0430\u0442 \xab\u0418\u043c\u0430\u043c\u0431\u0430\u044f\u043b\u0434\u044b\xbb'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122279/discussion-between-tomasz-jakub-rup-and--).